# Standardized ways to pack multiple values into one atomic

Tags: c++, multithreading, bit-manipulation, atomic, c++17

Assume I have two atomic variables of type int32, I could instead chose to represent them as `std::atomic<int64> both` and reserve the first 32 bits for my first int and the last for my second int.

This seems like quite a space & time saver on x64 architectures, not to mention it allows for all sorts of black magic since one can abstract over various operations and make them atomic:

```
first == a && second == b
```

becomes

```
both == ( int64(a) + int64(b) << 32 )
//Or some such... I'm not 100% sure this is correct but you get the idea
```

The one problem with this trick that I see is that I'm not particularly found with operating at the bit level and C++ is not very kind when it comes to operating at the bit level, especially once you try to accomplish more complex operations or pack more than two variables (e.g. two numbers and several bools) into the same atomic.

So I'm wondering if there is a standardized way to apply this kind of trick. A pattern or even std functionality that is easily recognizable by other coders when seen and easier to work with for the implementer? Likewise, is this pattern useful enough to warrant such a standardization, or does its usefulness quickly become obsolete when compared to the possible annoyances and UB it can bring?

Comment: Are you looking for bitfields?

Comment: What is the purpose of the integers? Could they be stored in a `std::pair` or `std::tupple`? A structure? A class?

Comment: Oh and the most important option of all: *Don't do anything!* While it might save a few bytes here and there, working with "two" integers packed in a single variable means the savings in memory will be offset by more operations needed to work with the values, leading to worse performance. And not to mention that the code will be harder to read, understand and most importantly maintain. Packing the values seems like a premature optimization to me, and those are almost always bad.

Comment: You should also check what your compiler does when storing two 32-bit values in a (64-bit) struct. Perhaps it can already load and store the struct atomically: https://godbolt.org/g/pZ7jQf

Comment: @ Bo Persson ... ok, I was completely unaware that placing the atomic template over any 64 bit value is possible. In hindsight it does make sense, thank you.

Comment: @ Some programmer dude It seems that pair and tupple aren't trivialy copyable in the versions of glibc++ and libc++ I have... so i don't think that's an option. Also, there's a reason I specifically asked for a "tidy" way of doing this and I don't plan to optimize any production code with it... it's more for messing around and trying various optimization, know before you need type thing

Answer (score 3):

C++ supports aggregate types like  structs, including assignment of the whole struct.
`struct foo { int a,b; }` is a 64-bit type containing two members.

`std::atomic<foo>` is lock-free in normal compilers exactly the same as `std::atomic<int64_t>`

As Alex's answer points out, you should avoid padding for alignment between members (or after the last member), and make sure the size is a power of 2.  (2, 4, or 8 bytes.  Or 16 bytes if your C++ implementation can efficiently make that lock-free, like on some AArch64, and recent x86-64 with up-to-date library support that uses 128-bit load/store on CPUs with AVX.)

---

If you want efficient read-only access to just the first or second member (like for a pointer + ABA counter), C++ is bad at that, or compilers are bad at optimizing `auto tmp = shared.load(acquire);` / use only `tmp.a` (or `tmp.ptr` or whatever you called the first member).  It would be safe on normal ISAs to make asm that really only loaded the first member, not the whole object, and that's potentially much cheaper (e.g. for the first 8 bytes of a 16-byte object on x86-64.)

You can hack something up with `std::atomic_ref` that will technically have UB but pretty reliably compile to safe asm.  Just make sure all writes write the full object.  Or before C++20, see [How can I implement ABA counter with c++11 CAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984153/how-can-i-implement-aba-counter-with-c11-cas) for the same hack with a union of a 16-byte atomic object with a struct of two 8-byte atomic halves.  And some details about x86 `lock cmpxchg16b` which until recently was x86-64's only documented / guaranteed safe way to do a lock-free atomic `.load()` of 16 bytes.  (Now, it's documented that a 16-byte SIMD load is atomic, but that still means you have to bounce the data from an XMM reg back to a GPR.  So it's still worth optimizing a load to just load the 8 bytes you want if you don't need a snapshot of the whole object.)

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the answer by @Peter Cordes, you would want to use struct directly in atomic, like `struct s { ... }; std::atomic<S> ...`.

To make sure the struct does not give extra overhead comparing to integer, consider the following:

- Avoid padding bits. Starting in C++20, the compiler has to skip padding bits during comparison for `compare_exchange_*`, see [p0528](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0528r3.html). It is not efficient in some architectures, including x86, also an `std::atomic` implementation may fail to make this efficient even with LL/SC implementation of `compare_exchange_*`.
- Avoid odd `sizeof`. Some STL implementation may not pad structure to complete to `uint64_t`, resulting in non-lock-free atomic. And sure you don't want to overflow the 64 bit. So consider `static_assert` on the structure size

---

Underlying integer type gives advantage of having arithmetic (`add`) and logic (`and`, `not`, `xor`) operations, which can be useful to manipulate sub-integers (arithmetic may overflow, but this is not a problem for highest sub-integer)

Comment: Good point about supporting `fetch_and` etc. on the whole object; that could be relevant for some use-cases, but C++ prevents you from doing that with `std::atomic<struct foo>`.  So I guess `std::atomic<uint64_t>` and `std::bit_cast<struct foo>( tmp_val )` which verifies the matching type sizes and PODness of the struct.

Answer (score 0):

The way to get around Read-Then-Write with atomics is using a loop:

```
void setBit(atomic<int64_t>& bitset, int bit)
{
  int64_t val = 1LL << bit;
  int64_t prev = bitset;
  while ((!(bitset & val)) && 
         !bitset.compare_exchange_weak(prev, (prev | val))
    ;
}
```

You can extend this method to create generic bitwise operation functions

Comment: This is not really what I'm after, though maybe the question is poorly worded. What I'm looking for is more similar to @Bo Persson answers, ways to operate with the values without having to do direct operations on bits and without having to do extra operations (which would defeat the whole point of this optimization anyway).

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer not to deal with shift and bitmask operations, you could cast the value to a pointer having the appropriate size and use simple pointer arithmetic or array index notation to access/store the values you require

Modern C++ enhusiasts will balk at this, but the following demonstrates the two approaches are equivalent (at least functionally, I've not compared if the emitted assembly matches though I'd expect it to be comparable)

In this example, I'm packing 4 x int8 values into a single int32

```
int32_t packed_values = 0x01020304;  // packed values [4, 3, 2, 1]

// pointer cast + array dereference approach
int8_t *unpacked_values = (int8_t *)&packed_values;

printf("packed value 0 == %d", unpacked_values[0]);
printf("packed value 1 == %d", unpacked_values[1]);
printf("packed value 2 == %d", unpacked_values[2]);
printf("packed value 3 == %d", unpacked_values[3]);

// shift mask approach
int8_t value0 = (packed_values & 0x000000FF);
int8_t value1 = (packed_values & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
int8_t value2 = (packed_values & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
int8_t value3 = (packed_values & 0xFF000000) >> 24;

printf("shift/mast value 0 == %d", value0);
printf("shift/mast value 1 == %d", value1);
printf("shift/mast value 2 == %d", value2);
printf("shift/mast value 3 == %d", value3);

assert (value0 == unpacked_values[0]);
assert (value1 == unpacked_values[1]);
assert (value2 == unpacked_values[2]);
assert (value3 == unpacked_values[3]);
```

Be mindful of endianness if your target architecture differs

Comment: You at least need to use `char` instead of `int8_t`; character types have an exemption from the strict aliasing rule, which `int8_t` technically does not (it is *usually* a typedef of `signed char` but this is not guaranteed).

Comment: Good shout @Nate, that sounds like a good reason to prefer bitmask/shift rather than rely on pointer aliasing, particularly since while `char` might replace the use of `int8_t` in this example, it would not extend to larger types

Comment: Found some excellent reading about this here btw. The type punning section and references to memcpy are particularly illuminating 
 https://gist.github.com/shafik/848ae25ee209f698763cffee272a58f8