# Does std::atomic provide atomic behavior, regardless of ordering?

Tags: c++, concurrency, memory-model, stdatomic

If a variable is declared with the `std::atomic` template, such as `std::atomic<int>`, is it guaranteed that access via the methods in `std::atomic` will result in a *consistent* value (that is, one written by a write through the `std::atomic` methods) regardless of ordering?

As far as I know, this equivalent to asking whether *reads* or *writes* can be "torn" - that is, written or real in multiple parts visible at the ISA level.

Comment: See [the documentation for `std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic). It answers all of your questions. If you have a problem understanding some part of that documentation, you need to explain exactly what part of the description you're not sure about. Learning how to read technical documentation is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: As Sam says! [[[

Comment: This is not a real answer, but regardless of `std::atomic`, aligned writes that are the size of a pointer or smaller are atomic on all the major ISAs these day (x86/x86_64, ARM, AArch64). It's usually not sufficient for multithreaded scenarios, but for sure, bolting on `std::atomic` won't make matters worse.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - I scanned that document at some length, but I didn't see any reference to atomicity specifically.

Comment: Did you see the "well defined" part, in the very first paragraph, with the link to the memory_order specification, that goes, in excruciating detail, what happens to all the reads and writes?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - yes, I did. I also read the linked page, and it did have this note: _When a thread reads a value from a memory location, it may see the initial value, the value written in the same thread, or the value written in another thread._ However, this clearly isn't true for arbitrary reads and writes (which could be torn), and it doesn't restrict such access to `std::atomic` so it left me confused (i.e., the claim seems to be _too strong_ at least by itself). Finally, that text doesn't seem to appear in the standard, so I guess it was just invented by `cppreference`?

Comment: The restrictions imposed by various models prevent tears, by definition. In order to "tear" around an update you have to reorder around it, by definition.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - I don't think you can invoke "non-reordering" to show that no tearing occurs, since for example `mo_relaxed` allows essentially any ordering! So perhaps you just have to rely on the definition of "atomically" as Peter does in his answer, or perhaps the standard (which I do not have a copy of) has some other language which guarantees it (i.e., some kind of guarantee that reads on `std::atomic` will always read either the initial value or some written value, and not anything else - no "out of thin air" values).

Comment: I never claimed that all memory models prevent tearing. Individual atomic methods take a parameter that sets that operation's model. If the model prohibits reordering that would result in a tear, then there's no tearing. If it doesn't, then there may be. This is not complicated.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - now it seems like it is getting complicated (to be fair, I never heard anyone try to claim that memory model issues are anything but simultaneously complicated and unintuitive)! So is there _any_ model that allows reordering that would result in a tear? I'm still at a loss for how reordering is related to tearing: I think you can, for example, allow arbitrary unconstrained reordering but still prohibit tearing (and that's exactly what `std::memory_order_relaxed` seems to do).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Atomic, [from the Greek *atom* meaning *indivisible*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/atom#Etymology_2), is synonymous with "no tearing".  It means that the entire operation happens indivisbly. 
 Everything you can do with a `std::atomic` type is always atomic (no tearing).

[C++14 draft N4140](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4653479/224132) section *29.3 Order and consistency* is the first part of that chapter that gets down to details.  One of the very first points is (1.4):

> [ Note: Atomic operations specifying `memory_order_relaxed` are relaxed with respect to memory ordering.
>   **Implementations must still guarantee that any given atomic access to a particular atomic object be indivisible
>   with respect to all other atomic accesses to that object**. — end note ]

As far as technical language that lays out the atomicity requirement, every operation (like `.store()`, `.load()`, `.fetch_add()`) is defined with language like:

> § **29.6.5 Requirements for operations on atomic types**
>
> ```
> void atomic_store(volatile A * object, C desired) noexcept;
> void atomic_store(A * object, C desired) noexcept;
> void atomic_store_explicit(volatile A * object, C desired, memory_order order) noexcept;
> void atomic_store_explicit(A * object, C desired, memory_order order) noexcept;
> void A ::store(C desired, memory_order order = memory_order_seq_cst) volatile noexcept;
> void A ::store(C desired, memory_order order = memory_order_seq_cst) noexcept;
> ```
>
> 9. Requires: The order argument shall not be `memory_order_consume`, `memory_order_acquire`, nor
>      `memory_order_acq_rel`.
> 10. Effects: **Atomically replaces the value** pointed to by object or by this with the value of desired.
>       Memory is affected according to the value of order.

And so on, using the word *Atomically* in every case it applies.

Instead of repeating themselves for `add`/`+`,  `sub`/`-`, and so for `|`, `&`, and `^`, they have a key/op table that applies to this block:

> ```
> C atomic_fetch_key (volatile A * object, M operand) noexcept;
> C atomic_fetch_key (A * object, M operand) noexcept;
> C atomic_fetch_key _explicit(volatile A * object, M operand, memory_order order) noexcept;
> C atomic_fetch_key _explicit(A * object, M operand, memory_order order) noexcept;
> C A ::fetch_key (M operand, memory_order order = memory_order_seq_cst) volatile noexcept;
> C A ::fetch_key (M operand, memory_order order = memory_order_seq_cst) noexcept;
> ```
>
> - 28 **Effects: Atomically replaces the value** pointed to by object or by
>     this with the result of the computation applied to the value pointed
>     to by object or by this and the given operand. Memory is affected
>     according to the value of order. These operations are atomic
>     read-modify-write operations (1.10).
> - 29 **Returns: Atomically, the value
>     pointed to** by object or by this immediately before the effects.
> - 30
>     Remark: For signed integer types, arithmetic is defined to use two’s
>     complement representation. There are no undefined results. For address
>     types, the result may be an undefined address, but the operations
>     otherwise have no undefined behavior.

---

The only thing that's optional is ordering / synchronization with loads/stores in other threads (for atomicity without synchronization, use `memory_order_relaxed`).

In fact, there's no way to "turn off" atomicity for loading a wide type where that's expensive (e.g. before [a CAS on `atomic<pointer_and_ABAcounter>` which compiles to `lock cmpxchg16b`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984153/how-can-i-implement-aba-counter-with-c11-cas/38991835#38991835) on x86). I used a union hack in that answer to efficiently load the struct.

And more importantly, the union is a workaround for gcc not optimizing `ptr_and_counter.ptr` to a load of just the pointer, which I think is safe at least on x86.  Instead gcc insists on atomically loading the whole struct and *then* getting the pointer from the result.  That's very bad when it's a 16-byte struct on x86-64, and fairly bad on x86-32.  (See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80835)

Comment: Thanks for the standard quote. It's a bit interesting that here they introduce a new term, _indivisible_ to describe how values must be atomic, since it I guess it would be weird to say "atomic values must still be atomic". It's also interesting they mention this as in the context of `relaxed` as in "they must still be indivisible" - but do they mention the overall indivisibility elsewhere?

Comment: @BeeOnRope: yes.  And the wording in the relaxed section implies that other orderings have the property too.  What has you wondering if atomics are always atomic?  I think it's pretty clear that barring compiler bugs, they are always atomic.

Comment: I think I was sleepy or drunk when I asked the question, but then rather than deleting I still wanted to see the text which spells it out. I don't have a copy of the standard but if it has text like "will read a value which was written by some other thread" like cppreference does, then I guess that's it.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: You can have a pdf copy of the draft standard if you click the link I added...  If you find the language you're looking for, feel free to edit this answer.  I agree it would be good to have this question answered with the best possible quote from the standard, but don't have time to go digging for it.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: updated with technical language from the standard.