# is_lock_free() returned false after upgrading to MacPorts gcc 7.3

Tags: c++, gcc, atomic, lock-free, gcc7

Previously, with Apple LLVM 9.1.0, `is_lock_free()` on 128-bit structures have returned true. To have complete `std::optional` support, I then upgraded to MacPorts gcc 7.3. During my first try to compile, I encountered this notorious showstopper linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___atomic_compare_exchange_16", referenced from:
```

I know that I may need to add `-latomic`. With Apple LLVM 9.1.0, I don't need it, and I have a very bad feeling about this. If it's lock-free, you usually should not need to link to any additional library, the compiler alone is able to handle it. Otherwise, it may just be lock-based and require support from additional library. Just as I have feared, after adding `-latomic`, build succeeded, but `is_lock_free()` returned false.

I do think gcc 7.3 and its standard library implementation are fine. It may just be some configuration problem on my side. As a matter of fact, I didn't do any configuration. I simply installed the MacPorts gcc and done. Any idea what I may be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer myself [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38991835/1348273).

> gcc7 and later will call libatomic instead of inlining `lock cmpxchg16b`, and will return false from `atomic_is_lock_free` ([for reasons including that it's so slow it's not what users expect `is_lock_free` to mean](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80835)), but at least for now the libatomic implementation still uses `lock cmpxchg16b` on targets where that instruction is available.  (It can even segfault for read-only atomic objects, so it's really not ideal.)

Comment: Yup.  128-bit lock-free was always a little weird because `-mcx16` was required to inline `lock cmpxchg16b`.  But apparently even on older gcc, you'd get `lock cmpxchg16b` in libatomic if supported, with runtime CPU detection I guess.  (https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2017-01/msg02344.html).  I didn't check; that's based on the wording of Torvald Riegel's message about the patch that implemented the change.

Comment: @PeterCordes The thing is, even with `-mcx16`, `is_lock_free()` will return false (not inlined). I will write a runtime test function to genuinely check whether it is lock-free, and will update the answer then.

Comment: I was talking about gcc6 and earlier.  That's why I said "was" (i.e. before that patch), but I should have been explicit with the start of my previous comment.  On gcc6 and earlier with `-mcx16`, `is_lock_free` and `is_always_lock_free` reports true for 16-byte objects.  Without `-mcx16`, I'm not sure; `is_lock_free` may check at runtime for `lock cmpxchg16b` support.  But `always_lock_free` would be false.