# How is std::atomic_ref implemented for non-atomic types?

Tags: c++, c++20, stdatomic, stdmutex

I am wondering how can [`std::atomic_ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref) be implemented efficiently (one `std::mutex` per object) for non-atomic objects as the following property seems rather hard to enforce:

> Atomic operations applied to an object through an atomic_ref are atomic with respect to atomic operations applied through any other atomic_ref referencing the same object.

In particular, the following code:

```
void set(std::vector<Big> &objs, size_t i, const Big &val) {
    std::atomic_ref RefI{objs[i]};
    RefI.store(val);
}
```

Seems quite difficult to implement as the `std::atomic_ref` would need to somehow pick every time the same `std::mutex` (unless it is a big master lock shared by all objects of the same type).

Am I missing something? Or each object is responsible to implement `std::atomic_ref` and therefore either be atomic or carry a `std::mutex`?

Comment: They probably have a map of addresses and mutexs and the look the mutex that relates to the objects address.  This allows multiple different references to guard a single object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The implementation is pretty much *exactly* the same as `std::atomic<T>` itself.  This is not a new problem.

See [Where is the lock for a std::atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298358/where-is-the-lock-for-a-stdatomic)  A typical implementation of `std::atomic` / `std::atomic_ref` a static hash table of locks, indexed by address, for non-lock-free objects.  Hash collisions only lead to extra contention, not a correctness problem.  (Deadlocks are still impossible; the locks are only used by atomic functions which never try to take 2 at a time.)

On GCC for example,  `std::atomic_ref` is just another way to invoke `__atomic_store` on an object.  (See the [GCC manual: atomic builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html))

The compiler knows whether `T` is small enough to be lock-free or not.  If not, it calls the libatomic library function which will use the lock.

---

Fun fact: that means it only works if the object has sufficient alignment for `atomic<T>`.  But on many 32-bit platforms including x86, `uint64_t` might only have 4-byte alignment.  `atomic_ref` on such an object will compile and run, but not actually be atomic if the compiler uses an SSE 8-byte load/store in 32-bit mode to implement it.  Fortunately there's no danger for objects that have `alignof(T) == sizeof(T)`, like most primitive types on 64-bit architectures.

This is why you need to allocate the underlying non-atomic object with the required alignment, e.g.

```
alignas(std::atomic_ref<T>::required_alignment) T foo;
```

or *check* that it must be sufficiently aligned already, e.g.

```
static_assert( std::atomic_ref<T>::required_alignment) == alignof(T), "T isn't *guaranteed* aligned enough for atomic_ref" );
```

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref/required_alignment

Comment: I hadn't realised `atomic<T>` was allowed on non-atomic types too (although that one could technically allocate a `mutex` itself, as it owns the object). Thanks for the explanation, it makes sense.

Answer (score 7):

An implementation can use a hash based on the address of the object to determine which of a set of locks to acquire while performing the operation.

Comment: This is actually how libstdc++ implements atomic operations on `shared_ptr` objects. https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B11/shared_ptr.cc

Comment: Said hash table would contain mutexes? When are they safe to free?

Comment: @Nonyme In the link I provided you can see that they have static storage duration.