# Is there any case that the atomicity of std::atomic is not guaranteed, when is_lock_free() == false?

Tags: c++, atomic, stdatomic

Even if `is_lock_free() == false` , typically maybe, the atomicity of std::atomic can be  guaranteed. Is that right?

I wander that there are computer environments or cases where the atomicity is not guaranteed, when `is_lock_free() == false`.

Comment: Not about atomicity, but another important restriction of non-lock-free atomics is you can't safely use them in async signal handlers, because they might deadlock with the main thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-lock-free atomics aren't address-free, so shared memory between two processes would mean they don't respect each other's lock.  (Same for two virtual mappings of a page holding the same atomic object in the same process, [unless the hash table of locks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298358/where-is-the-lock-for-a-stdatomic) is only indexed on the low bits of the address, the offset-within-page, but that would probably be a bad design.)

ISO C++ doesn't define memory-mapping functions or processes, so the standard itself doesn't go into much detail other than saying lock-free atomics should be address-free (which makes them work in shared memory).  That is the case on real-world implementations.

Otherwise it's always atomic.  The usual implementation mechanism is simple: use the address to index a table of spinlocks or mutexes.

Of course, this assumes a program free of undefined behaviour, but so does everything else in C++.  Any UB anywhere during the execution of a C++ program means all guarantees of anything before or after that point are out the window.

In practice there aren't a lot of ways you could break atomicity of a non-lock-free `std::atomic`, other than really obvious stuff like using `memcpy` or a plain-`uint64_t*` to access the object representation, instead of going through the `std::atomic<uint64_t>` class.

Lock-free std::atomic is actually easier to break with UB, e.g. by dereferencing an `atomic<T>*` that's not aligned to `alignof(std::atomic<T>)`.  On many ISAs that support unaligned loads/stores, that will run but not actually be atomic, because the C++ implementation was relying on hardware guarantees for atomicity of aligned loads and stores.