Why is there no atomic::try_load_for and try_store_for, similar to timed_mutex in C++?
I have a program where I want to guarantee that progress is made inside a loop because it needs to respond to safety critical events. My idea was to have a timeout for all function calls that can be made inside this loop, but I needed atomic data types. std::atomic<my_struct> would have been sufficient here, but there are no try_lock_for functions right? So why does something like the following not exist in stdlib C++ yet?
#ifndef TIMED_ATOMIC_HPP
#define TIMED_ATOMIC_HPP

#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <expected>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct is_shared_ptr : std::false_type {};

template <typename U>
struct is_shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<U>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_unique_ptr : std::false_type {};

template <typename U, typename D>
struct is_unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<U, D>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_raw_pointer : std::is_pointer<T> {};

template <typename T>
concept NotPointerType = !is_raw_pointer<T>::value && !is_unique_ptr<T>::value && !is_shared_ptr<T>::value;

template<typename T>
concept AllowedType = NotPointerType<T> && std::is_copy_constructible_v<T> && std::is_move_constructible_v<T>;

/// @brief Wrapper class to allow threadsafe access with a timeout. This is required because the robot state update thread should never hang because it is responsible for stopping the robot in case exit_flag is set.
template<typename T>
requires AllowedType<T>
class timed_atomic {
    private:
        std::timed_mutex mtx {};
        T value {};

    public:
        explicit timed_atomic(T initial_value) : value{initial_value} {}
        timed_atomic() = default;

        std::expected<T, std::monostate> try_load_for(std::chrono::microseconds timeout_us) {
            std::unique_lock lock{mtx, std::defer_lock};
            if(!lock.try_lock_for(timeout_us)) {
                return std::unexpected{std::monostate{}};
            }
            return value;
        }

        bool try_store_for(T new_value, std::chrono::microseconds timeout_us) {
            std::unique_lock lock{mtx, std::defer_lock};
            if(!lock.try_lock_for(timeout_us)) {
                return false;
            }
            value = std::move(new_value);
            return true;
        }
};

#endif

I tried looking for std::atomic::try_lock_for, similar to timed_mutex and found this C++20: How to wait on an atomic object with timeout?, but the wait function is something else I would say.
Update: Here is some more context: "Real-time" multithreaded design with timeouts

std::atomic has no locking functionality. Why would it have any kind try_lock or try_lock_for?

I am guessing no one bothered proposing it to the c++ committee

@ALX23z I am probably misunderstanding but afaik I can check with is_always_lock_free for a specific type. For my struct it was indeed not lock free so how does it work without lock under the hood then? CAS loop?

@HansMüller atomic are intended to be implemented via atomic instructions. It's not always possible but the interface is the same. The "lock free" is about how it is implemented. It still doesn't support any kind of locking API. Check out how libraries implement guarded variables. They tend to have very different design

What? Atomic that are not always lock free are just using mutexes under the hood as well? I read here that it's just a hashtable of mutexes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298358/where-is-the-lock-for-a-stdatomic

The intended use-case for std::atomic is types that are lock-free on the implementations you care about.  std::atomic<T>::is_always_lock_free() or a.is_lock_free().
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_always_lock_free
The fallback to locking for larger types on some system is just to enable portability.
For lock-free atomics, there is no try, just do.  (Insert "do not" joke here, I didn't think of a good one.)
Except when something like .fetch_or has to get implemented with a CAS retry loop on x86 if you use the return value in a way that doesn't allow lock bts (bit test-and-set), unlike .fetch_add which has a special instruction lock xadd.
The most common case does have a "try", though: compare_exchange_weak is just one LL/SC attempt which can have "spurious" failure due to contention for the cache line, even if the value actually matches.  A retry loop is needed to implement compare_exchange_strong on machines that only have load-linked/store-conditional atomics, like typical RISCs before the last few years where scalability to huge core counts became a big deal.  (ARMv8.1 has single-instruction atomic RMWs.)
Pure loads and pure stores never need to retry, unless implemented with LL/SC for types too wide to be atomic with plain loads/stores.  Such as int64_t on 32-bit ARM (Godbolt)
void store64(std::atomic<int64_t> &a, int64_t val){
    a.store(val, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}

store64(std::atomic<long long>&, long long):
        push    {r4, r5}
.L6:
        ldrexd  r4, r5, [r0]
        strexd  r1, r2, r3, [r0]
        cmp     r1, #0
        bne     .L6
        pop     {r4, r5}
        bx      lr

So there is a retry-loop here.  But ISO C++ doesn't expose LL/SC or CAS retries other than compare_exchange_weak.
It's still lock-free, at least if hardware does some arbitration to prevent live-lock on LL/SC systems if many cores are trying simultaneously, like letting a core hang onto ownership of a cache line for enough cycles to complete the SC part of a transaction as long as it isn't interrupted.

but based on your fallback to locking, it's just mutexes or spinlocks under the hood for more complex types right? I admit I should have mentioned that I only use this for non lock free types obviously, for double, int and bool in my code I use the std::atomic, but I had a struct containing a 6d Pose comprised of doubles and that was not lock free. However, I needed a guarantee that the lock never takes longer than a specified timeout or else it fails so that the robot could be disabled in a guaranteed time interval. Does that idea make sense or am I misunderstanding something in my approach?

@HansMüller: If you know your type is larger than 2 pointers, you know it won't be lock-free on any mainstream platforms.  (I guess you could maybe have a std::atomic that tried to use transactional memory on x86 or AArch64 if available, but currently they don't.)  So don't use std::atomic at all for that type; manually use a lock so you can do multiple operations on one object while holding the lock.  And if you need more control over the locking, like a timeout, you can get that if you do your own locking.

@HansMüller:   It wouldn't make sense for std::atomic<T> to have a try_lock_for member function; what would it do on lock-free types?  Always fail?  Maybe always succeed would make sense.  It would let you create deadlocks by trying to lock another atomic object while you still hold the lock on one.  I guess I could imagine having an extra parameter to functions like fetch_add and load, to specify a timeout if locking was used, but like I said, non-lock-free is just there for compatibility, not intended to be used intentionally when performance is really important I don't think.

I see, so my approach is wrong because I am using the term wrong? But I would still have to write a wrapper for it to use timed mutexes so that I do not expose the mutex to others and allow for deadlocks right?you are correct though that i had a few issues that could easily be resolved using a single timed mutex scope... I think the only reason i Skipped that option is that i did not want global mutexes

Actually i remembered my original reason: with a mutex i would have to lock to store the new desired pose, set the "movement_requested" flag  and only the  unlock again. During this time the other thread cannot make progress, or it can only check the atomic flag, but in that scenario we have arrived at my exact timed_atomic class again right?

@HansMüller: You can implement your own global (or static class-scoped to a wrapper or RAII helper class) hash table of mutexes or spinlocks indexed by object address like most std::atomic implementations do (Where is the lock for a std::atomic?), if that design choice seems good for your use-case, vs. one global mutex or a separate mutex for every object you might want to lock.  As long as you still never need to lock 2 at once, otherwise they could both hash to the same mutex and deadlock.

@HansMüller: I don't know what you're talking about with a movement_requested flag.  You could potentially use a mix of small lock-free std::atomic<> objects and larger objects that you take locks for, if that allows better parallelism while still maintaining correctness. Keeping an object locked across a couple operations instead of needing a CAS retry loop can be much better for throughput. e.g. x.lock();  / compute new value for x and store / x.unlock() (or scoped RAII, where the constructor takes a timeout), instead of lock / read x / unlock / compute / CAS / store / unlock / retry

Thanks a lot for your advice. Where can i do a writeup about more context and my current solution, should I edit my question?

@HansMüller: You could post a self-answer, and maybe modify the question a bit to make what you want to post work as an answer.  (e.g. describe the use-case you want this for, and say "what should I use instead of std::atomic if it's not intended for this?")  Your current solution should definitely go in an answer.  Or in a new question if you don't like it and want someone to suggest something better.

Done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79243314/real-time-multithreaded-design-with-timeouts
