"Real-time" multithreaded design with timeouts
This is a follow up question related to Why is there no atomic::try_load_for and try_store_for, similar to timed_mutex in C++? to provide some more context. I am trying to essentially write threadsafe robot control code by implementing a wrapper around the provided https://github.com/LouKordos/fanuc-ethernet-cpp
This library was specifically designed to only provide access from one thread and due to some issues with the implementation also on the robot side, one command takes up to 25ms. Since my application has a force/torque sensor that needs to be constantly monitored and the movement stopped when a threshold is exceeded, i cannot block for that long, so my approach is to put the robot communication stuff in a loop on a separate thread. It just updates a global state, like is_enabled, current_pose using my timed_atomic implementation in the question linked above, which are read operations and easier to do.
But then, I need to write stuff like velocity limit and desired pose to the robot from another thread. The easy way would just be to have another timed atomic, read that at every iteration of the robot update loop and send it to the robot, but i don't want to do that because communication takes too long and the loop would only run at about 10-20Hz. So I implmented "request flags" which tell the loop that someone has updated the desired pose and wants it to arrive at the robot.
Also, I use timed_atomic and all other functions have a timeout in the loop because at the end of the loop, when the global atomic exit flag is set, the robot is disabled. This is safety critical and the reason i need timeouts on everything including atomic ops, so that I can guarantee a time until the robot is disabled. I know I should use other methods for ESTOP but this is currently what I have available. Below is the relevant code, I have commented my reasoning and my main question is if this is the correct approach i.e.

Did I make the right decision to use my own timed_atomic as a threadsafe wrapper with a timeout for more complex objects? Honestly the complex object is just a 6d pose and some metadata, so like 10 doubles, but std::atomic cant make that lock free obviously.
Are my approaches explained in the comments to prevent race conditions correct? Or is there a simpler Version than using flags and tokens to make sure that thread scheduling does not interfere with all the flags etc. I was thinking about a cas loop but not sure how it would work. Also I did not want to use a (timed) mutex to simplify it by doing many Operations inside one lock because then the other thread would have to wait for the robot to receive the message, effectively blocking as if i had used the robot library directly.

std::atomic<bool> is_robot_enabled {};
// If false, normal skip and CNT movements are enabled!
std::atomic<bool> is_high_speed_skip_fine_enabled {};
static_assert(std::atomic<bool>::is_always_lock_free, "atomic bool is not lock free!");
static_assert(std::atomic<uint64_t>::is_always_lock_free, "atomic uint64_t is not lock free!");
static_assert(std::atomic<double>::is_always_lock_free, "atomic double is not lock free!");

std::atomic<bool> async_robot_movement_requested_flag {};
std::atomic<bool> high_speed_skip_fine_mode_requested_flag {};
std::atomic<bool> normal_skip_cnt_mode_requested_flag {};
std::atomic<bool> robot_disable_requested_flag {};
std::atomic<bool> velocity_limit_set_requested_flag {};
// DO NOT SET OUTSIDE OF ROBOT UPDATE THREAD! Used for checking from other threads if the movement has been sent to the robot successfully.
std::atomic<uint64_t> movement_requested_token {};
std::atomic<uint64_t> movement_started_token {};

std::atomic<uint64_t> velocity_limit_requested_token {};
std::atomic<uint64_t> velocity_limit_updated_token {};

timed_atomic<fanuc_ethernet::robot_pose> requested_pose_threadsafe {};
std::atomic<double> requested_velocity_limit {};
// Should only be written to by robot state update thread
timed_atomic<fanuc_ethernet::robot_pose> current_pose_threadsafe {};

// Pass by value since it will be copied to the internal atomic variable used in other threads
bool request_async_robot_movement(const fanuc_ethernet::robot_pose desired_pose, const Config& config, bool block) {
    ZoneScoped;
    if(requested_pose_threadsafe.try_store_for(desired_pose, std::chrono::microseconds{config.try_lock_timeout_us})) {
        auto token = movement_requested_token.fetch_add(1) + 1;
        // Using tokens prevents the scheduler from messing this up. If we used a flag, it would be possible that preemption stops execution at exactly this line, while the other thread processes the movement
        // and sets the flag to true. Then, this thread right here wakes up again, sets it to false and waits until it's true again. This is a race condition.
        // By using tokens instead, we can make sure that exactly this movement is processed in the other thread. We expect the value to be incremented by 1
        // and wait until the movement_started_token is set to exactly that value.
        // in this scenario, either the scheduler stops before the fetch_add (ok because requested flag is false still), or between fetch_add and requested = true (also ok because update loop does not process the new movement yet)
        // or after requested_flag.store (ok because movement_started_token will match the variable token, so it's already updated), otherwise it will spin.
        async_robot_movement_requested_flag.store(true);

        while(block && !exit_flag.test() && movement_started_token.load() != token){
            // Spin / Busy wait
        }
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

void request_high_speed_skip_fine_mode(bool block) {
    ZoneScoped;
    if(is_high_speed_skip_fine_enabled.load()) {
        return;
    }
    high_speed_skip_fine_mode_requested_flag.store(true);
    normal_skip_cnt_mode_requested_flag.store(false);

    while(block && !exit_flag.test() && !is_high_speed_skip_fine_enabled.load()) {
        // Spin to prevent unscheduling CPU, although this might not be the best idea
    }
}

void request_normal_skip_cnt_mode(bool block) {
    ZoneScoped;
    if(!is_high_speed_skip_fine_enabled.load()) {
        return;
    }
    normal_skip_cnt_mode_requested_flag.store(true);
    high_speed_skip_fine_mode_requested_flag.store(false);

    while(block && !exit_flag.test() && is_high_speed_skip_fine_enabled.load()) {
        // Spin to prevent unscheduling CPU, although this might not be the best idea
    }
}

void request_disable_robot(bool block) {
    ZoneScoped;
    robot_disable_requested_flag.store(true);
    while(block && !exit_flag.test() && is_robot_enabled.load()) {

    }
}

// Pass by value since it will be copied to the internal atomic variable used in other threads
void request_velocity_limit(const double vel_limit, bool block) {
    ZoneScoped;
    requested_velocity_limit.store(vel_limit);
    auto token = velocity_limit_requested_token.fetch_add(1) + 1;
    // Using tokens prevents the scheduler from messing this up. If we used a flag, it would be possible that preemption stops execution at exactly this line, while the other thread processes the movement
    // and sets the flag to true. Then, this thread right here wakes up again, sets it to false and waits until it's true again. This is a race condition.
    // By using tokens instead, we can make sure that exactly this movement is processed in the other thread. We expect the value to be incremented by 1
    // and wait until the movement_started_token is set to exactly that value.
    // in this scenario, either the scheduler stops before the fetch_add (ok because requested flag is false still), or between fetch_add and requested = true (also ok because update loop does not process the new movement yet)
    // or after requested_flag.store (ok because movement_started_token will match the variable token, so it's already updated), otherwise it will spin.
    velocity_limit_set_requested_flag.store(true);

    while(block && !exit_flag.test() && velocity_limit_updated_token.load() != token){
        // Spin / Busy wait
    }
}
std::atomic<bool> update_robot_state_init_finished_flag {};

void update_robot_state(std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> logger, const Config& config) {
    logger->info("update_robot_state init");

    fanuc_ethernet::FANUCRobot robot{config.robot_ip, eipScanner::utils::LogLevel::WARNING};
    logger->debug("Robot object initialized");
    auto init_result = robot.initialize_connection();

    if(!init_result.has_value()) {
        logger->error("Failed to connect to FANUC robot, exiting: {0}", init_result.error());
        exit_flag.test_and_set();
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{300});
    robot.set_velocity_limit(config.global_velocity_limit);
    robot.set_mode_cnt_normal_skip();
    is_high_speed_skip_fine_enabled.store(false);
    update_robot_state_init_finished_flag.store(true);

    while(!exit_flag.test()) {
        FrameMarkNamed("update_robot_state_loop");
        ZoneScoped;
        // After each message to the robot, we have to check exit_flag again because each message takes ~10ms...
        auto enabled_res = robot.is_enabled();
        if(!enabled_res.has_value()) {
            logger->error("Error while trying to get robot enabled state, exiting: {0}", enabled_res.error());
            break;
        }
        bool enabled_state_temp = enabled_res.value();
        is_robot_enabled.store(enabled_state_temp);
        logger->trace("enabled_state_temp={0}", enabled_state_temp);

        // TODO: Save current pose, enabled, setpoint pose to TimescaleDB
        if(exit_flag.test()) {
            break;
        }

        // Do this in one operation, meaning that no race conditions can occur when request function_movement is being called at the same time and the flag is already true.
        // This way, it can either be 
        // 1. True when checking, meaning the if statement sets it to false, and updates the robot to move to the desired pose (this desired pose has already been set before setting the flag to true by request_...)
        // 2. False, meaning it sets temp to false (don't care about that), skips the iteration, and on the next iteration the desired pose will have been updated and the flag is set to true.
        bool temp {true};
        if(velocity_limit_set_requested_flag.compare_exchange_strong(temp, false)) {
            ZoneScopedN("Update desired velocity limit");

            auto requested_vel_limit = requested_velocity_limit.load();
            logger->debug("Sending velocity limit to robot: {0}", requested_vel_limit);
            robot.set_velocity_limit(requested_vel_limit);
            velocity_limit_updated_token.store(velocity_limit_requested_token.load());
        }

        if(exit_flag.test()) {
            break;
        }

        // Do this in one operation, meaning that no race conditions can occur when request function is being called at the same time and the flag is already true.
        // This way, it can either be 
        // 1. True when checking, meaning the if statement sets it to false, and updates the robot to move to the desired pose (this desired pose has already been set before setting the flag to true by request_...)
        // 2. False, meaning it sets temp to false (don't care about that), skips the iteration, and on the next iteration the desired pose will have been updated and the flag is set to true.
        temp = true;
        if(async_robot_movement_requested_flag.compare_exchange_strong(temp, false)) {
            ZoneScopedN("Update desired pose");

            auto requested_pose_res = requested_pose_threadsafe.try_load_for(std::chrono::microseconds{config.try_lock_timeout_us});
            if(requested_pose_res.has_value()) {
                logger->debug("Sending async move to robot: {0}", requested_pose_res.value());
                robot.move_to_pos_async(requested_pose_res.value(), false);
                movement_started_token.store(movement_requested_token.load());
                // Since we know that it's enabled now
                is_robot_enabled.store(true);
            }
            else {
                logger->error("try_lock_for on requested pose exceeded, exiting.");
                exit_flag.test_and_set();
            }
        }

        if(exit_flag.test()) {
            break;
        }

        auto current_pose_res = robot.read_current_pose();
        if(!current_pose_res.has_value()) {
            exit_flag.test_and_set();
            logger->error("Failed to get current pose, exiting: {0}", current_pose_res.error());
            break;
        }
        logger->trace("In update_robot_state loop: {0}", current_pose_res.value());
        if(!current_pose_threadsafe.try_store_for(current_pose_res.value(), std::chrono::microseconds{config.try_lock_timeout_us})) {
            exit_flag.test_and_set();
            logger->error("Timeout while trying to set threadsafe current pose, exiting.");
            break;
        }

        if(exit_flag.test()) {
            break;
        }

        // Do this in one operation, meaning that no race conditions can occur when request function is being called at the same time and the flag is already true.
        // This way, it can either be 
        // 1. True when checking, meaning the if statement sets it to false, and updates the robot to move to the desired pose (this desired pose has already been set before setting the flag to true by request_...)
        // 2. False, meaning it sets temp to false (don't care about that), skips the iteration, and on the next iteration the desired pose will have been updated and the flag is set to true.
        temp = true;
        if(high_speed_skip_fine_mode_requested_flag.compare_exchange_strong(temp, false)) {
            ZoneScopedN("Set high speed skip FINE mode");

            logger->debug("Enabling high speed skip mode...");
            auto res = robot.set_mode_fine_high_speed_skip();
            if(res.has_value()) {
                is_high_speed_skip_fine_enabled.store(true);
                logger->debug("Successfully enabled high speed skip mode.");
            }
            else {
                logger->error("Error while trying to set high speed skip mode, exiting: {0}", res.error());
                exit_flag.test_and_set();
            }
        }

        if(exit_flag.test()) {
            break;
        }

        // Do this in one operation, meaning that no race conditions can occur when request function is being called at the same time and the flag is already true.
        // This way, it can either be 
        // 1. True when checking, meaning the if statement sets it to false, and updates the robot to move to the desired pose (this desired pose has already been set before setting the flag to true by request_...)
        // 2. False, meaning it sets temp to false (don't care about that), skips the iteration, and on the next iteration the desired pose will have been updated and the flag is set to true.
        temp = true;
        if(normal_skip_cnt_mode_requested_flag.compare_exchange_strong(temp, false)) {
            ZoneScopedN("Set normal skip CNT mode");

            logger->debug("Enabling normal speed skip CNT mode...");
            auto res = robot.set_mode_cnt_normal_skip();
            if(res.has_value()) {
                is_high_speed_skip_fine_enabled.store(false);
                logger->debug("Successfully enabled normal speed skip CNT mode.");
            }
            else {
                logger->error("Error while trying to set normal speed speed skip CNT mode, exiting: {0}", res.error());
                exit_flag.test_and_set();
            }
        }

        if(exit_flag.test()) {
            break;
        }

        // Do this in one operation, meaning that no race conditions can occur when request function is being called at the same time and the flag is already true.
        // This way, it can either be 
        // 1. True when checking, meaning the if statement sets it to false, and updates the robot to move to the desired pose (this desired pose has already been set before setting the flag to true by request_...)
        // 2. False, meaning it sets temp to false (don't care about that), skips the iteration, and on the next iteration the desired pose will have been updated and the flag is set to true.
        temp = true;
        if(robot_disable_requested_flag.compare_exchange_strong(temp, false)) {
            ZoneScopedN("Disable robot");

            logger->debug("Disabling robot as requested...");
            auto res = robot.disable_robot();
            if(res.has_value()) {
                robot_disable_requested_flag.store(false);
                logger->debug("Successfully disabled robot.");
            }
            else {
                logger->error("Error while trying to disable robot, exiting: {0}", res.error());
                exit_flag.test_and_set();
            }
        }
    }

    logger->info("Exit flag true, stopping robot and exiting robot update thread.");
    for(int retry = 0; retry < 3; retry++) {
        auto disable_res = robot.disable_robot();
        if(disable_res.has_value()) {
            logger->info("Robot successfully disabled, exiting.");
            break;
        }
        else {
            logger->warn("Disable failed, retrying: {0}", disable_res.error());
        }
    }
}

// Example for how to use the code from another thread
void move_to_pose_sync(std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> logger, const Config& config, const fanuc_ethernet::robot_pose& desired_pose, std::string movement_name) {
    ZoneScoped;
    logger->debug("Starting movement [{0}] to {1}", movement_name, desired_pose);
    while(!exit_flag.test() && is_robot_enabled.load()) {
        logger->trace("Robot is still enabled, waiting until previous movement is done.");
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{1});
    }
    logger->debug("Requesting async movement...");
    if(!request_async_robot_movement(desired_pose, config, true)) {
        logger->error("Failed to request movement, exiting.");
        exit_flag.test_and_set();
        return;
    }
    logger->debug("Requested async movement, waiting.");
    while(!exit_flag.test() && is_robot_enabled.load()) {
        auto res = current_pose_threadsafe.try_load_for(std::chrono::microseconds{500});
        if(res.has_value()) {
            logger->trace("Waiting for movement to finish, current pose: {0}", res.value());
        }
        else {
            logger->trace("Waiting for mvoement to finish...");
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{1});
    }
    logger->debug("Finshed movement [{0}] to {1}.", movement_name, desired_pose);
}

Edit: I was advised to add the timed_atomic code shown in my linked previous question:
#ifndef TIMED_ATOMIC_HPP
#define TIMED_ATOMIC_HPP

#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <expected>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct is_shared_ptr : std::false_type {};

template <typename U>
struct is_shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<U>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_unique_ptr : std::false_type {};

template <typename U, typename D>
struct is_unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<U, D>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_raw_pointer : std::is_pointer<T> {};

template <typename T>
concept NotPointerType = !is_raw_pointer<T>::value && !is_unique_ptr<T>::value && !is_shared_ptr<T>::value;

template<typename T>
concept AllowedType = NotPointerType<T> && std::is_copy_constructible_v<T> && std::is_move_constructible_v<T>;

/// @brief Wrapper class to allow threadsafe access with a timeout. This is required because the robot state update thread should never hang because it is responsible for stopping the robot in case exit_flag is set.
template<typename T>
requires AllowedType<T>
class timed_atomic {
    private:
        std::timed_mutex mtx {};
        T value {};

    public:
        explicit timed_atomic(T initial_value) : value{initial_value} {}
        timed_atomic() = default;

        std::expected<T, std::monostate> try_load_for(std::chrono::microseconds timeout_us) {
            std::unique_lock lock{mtx, std::defer_lock};
            if(!lock.try_lock_for(timeout_us)) {
                return std::unexpected{std::monostate{}};
            }
            return value;
        }

        bool try_store_for(T new_value, std::chrono::microseconds timeout_us) {
            std::unique_lock lock{mtx, std::defer_lock};
            if(!lock.try_lock_for(timeout_us)) {
                return false;
            }
            value = std::move(new_value);
            return true;
        }
};

#endif


Your [mcve] omits a definition for the timed_atomic<>  class which is the focus of your question.  Off-site links aren't sufficient.  I assume that's one reason people are downvoting.  I don't have time tonight to read the question in any detail.

@PeterCordes there's an implementation in the previous question
