# Validity of InterlockedCompareExchange64 + Read32 operations mix

Tags: c++, x86, 64-bit, atomic, interlocked

Objective:
I have a chunk of memory shared between several x86/x64 processes/threads.
Inside it I have QWORD (64 bit) variable aligned on 8-byte boundary.
That variable is accessed by one writer and several readers simultaneously, mix of x86 and x64 readers/writers is possible.
Let's say that variable is declared/named as QWORD qwSharedVar, and compiler is MSVC with /volatile:ms behaviour.

Suppositions:

1.
If writer process is x64, it writes a new value in a such way:

```
*reinterpret_cast< volatile QWORD* >( &qwSharedVar ) = qwNewValue;
```

2. 

If writer process is x86, it writes a new value in a such way:

```
_InterlockedCompareExchange64( reinterpret_cast< volatile __int64* >( &qwSharedVar ), qwNewValue, qwSharedVar );
```

3. 

If reader process is x64, it reads a shared value in a such way:

```
QWORD qwValueNow = *reinterpret_cast< volatile QWORD* >( &qwSharedVar );
```

4. 

If reader process is x86, it reads a shared value in a such way:

```
QWORD qwValueNow = _InterlockedCompareExchange64( reinterpret_cast< volatile __int64* >( &qwSharedVar ), 0, 0 );
```

5. 

If reader process is x86 or x64, and it wants to read only lower DWORD of shared value, then:

```
DWORD dwValueNow = *reinterpret_cast< volatile DWORD* >( &qwSharedVar );
```

Are those suppositions legal?
I'm especially worried about point 5, where mix of accesses through "lock cmpxchg8b" and "mov dword ptr" is possible.

Comment: The x86 memory model is well-defined for all of these and works the way you'd expect / hope, including a mix of qword load, stores, or CAS, combined with dword loads of either half.  Related: [How can I implement ABA counter with c++11 CAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38984153)/ is an equivalent problem of mixing qword access with `lock cmpxchg16b` in 64-bit mode.  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info has some links to x86 formal memory model stuff, but basically a wide store or RMW can be reloaded by any narrower load just like if it was the same width reload.

Comment: For #2, you need to check that the cmpxchg succeeded; otherwise the value wasn’t written.

Comment: Also note that you don't need to do any of this manually; use `std::atomic<uint64_t>` (with std::memory_order_relaxed if you want cheap stores).  You might need to check that it's lock_free for all the builds you care about; GCC can do lock-free 64-bit atomics in 32-bit mode (using SSE2 movq load/store).  I don't know for sure that MSVC does that; it might want to fall back to locking for 64-bit atomics in 32-bit mode, which would be ABI-incompatible with lock-free access.

Comment: >> For #2, you need to check that the cmpxchg succeeded; otherwise the value wasn’t written.

Yes, it's clear. I wrote simplified code so as not to distract from the main question.
Furthermore, one-writer scheme doesn't require checks or till-succeeded cycles.
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I realized the “one writer” part after I had written the comment.