# "Downcasting" a std::atomic_ref<T>

Tags: c++, multithreading, casting, stdatomic

Is it possible to downcast between `std::atomic_ref<T>` and `std::atomic_ref<U>` where `U` is a subclass of `T`?

I tried the following code which didn't work.

```
template<typename T>
std::atomic_ref<T> World::getComponentByID(componentInstanceId uuid) const {
    static componentTypeId key = stringHash(typeid(T).name());
    return components.at(uuid);
}
```

The template parameter `T` was position (a subclass of `Component`). `components` is a map of `componentInstanceId`s to `Component`s .

`error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'const std::atomic_ref<Component>' to 'std::atomic_ref<Position>`

Comment: I think you mean "upcasting" rather than "downcasting"?

Comment: I am casting from a superclass `Component` to a subclass `Position` @ruakh.

Comment: I see. In that case, I'm kind of surprised that you tried the code that you did, seeing as C++ *never* allows implicit downcasts so far as I'm aware. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah. I am trying to do an explicit downcast, but I can't find out how to do that either.

Comment: Ah, OK, understood.

Comment: you should provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I doubt this is possible at the moment. To make the reference atomic, accessing an `atomic_ref` object creates a temporary object under the hood. And since you can’t get the reference of a temporary object, you can’t get a `atomic_ref<U>` from `atomic_ref<T>`. Unless the library has direct support for the downcasting feature, which stl doesn’t have it, I don’t think this would be possible.

Comment: [From cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref): "No subobject of an object referenced by an `atomic_ref` object may be concurrently referenced by any other `atomic_ref` object." This means it would be undefined behavior to have an `atomic_ref` referencing an object of derived class and another referencing its base class subobject, as the cast you envision would require.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve what I desire? Atomic access to an object with downcasting? @IgorTandetnik

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't make any sense to me. Sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why are you holding `components` by `atomic_ref` - is there concurrent access to them somehow? Where and how do you store actual `Component` objects that those references refer to? Show a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usage of `atomic_ref` this way does not make sense.  (Even in `lock_free` cases that make sense in assembly language, the ISO C++ standard doesn't expose that functionality.)

As @Igor Tandetnik pointed out, "No subobject of an object referenced by an atomic_ref object may be concurrently referenced by any other atomic_ref object."

One of reasons this rule exists is that for non-lock-free `atomic_ref` it implements pool of mutexes, so having sub-object with different pointer value will get you into a different mutex for a subobject, or even a mutex from a different pool, or it may happen that sub-object is lock-free, but the bigger object is lock-based.

Additionally, possible pointer adjustments may defeat alignment, and it is mandatory for value referenced by `atomic_ref` to respect `atomic_ref<T>::required_alignment`.

---

`atomic_ref` is not a general purpose facility. Perhaps you just need to protect your objects with `std::mutex` or `std::shared_mutex` instead.

Comment: *Usage of atomic_ref this way does not make sense.*  If both the full object and the sub-object are lock_free, then It does make sense in asm on real CPUs, and would work as a hack in C++ if written correctly.  Instead of saying it didn't make sense, I'd say this is asm functionality that is not exposed by ISO C++.

Comment: Similar problem to [How can I implement ABA counter with c++11 CAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38991835) where you want efficient reads, but current compilers won't optimize a read of a 16-byte `atomic` and then only using 1 member into just an 8-byte load.  I hacked around it with a `union` between an `atomic<16byte>` and a struct of two `atomic<8-byte>` which is obviously not well-defined in ISO C++ but does compile to good asm.  All because compilers suck at `16byte.load().member`.