# Are _Atomic members of unions a good idea?

Tags: c, union, atomic, compare-and-swap

I'm using _Atomic integers inside of unions, such as:

```
union dedup_option_seq {
    struct {
        uint32_t seq       :18;     // enough bits for seq
        uint32_t not_empty :1;      // inverted so that zero is empty
    };
    _Atomic uint32_t value;
};
```

I can then happily use `&foo.value` as a parameter in the `atomic_...()` functions.

I can set unions' values using the syntax:

```
union dedup_option_seq foo = {
    .seq = 42,
    .not_empty = 1
};
```

It's all working nicely, but am I causing any undefined behaviour, or other issues, when using unions with an _Atomic member?

Comment: C++ added [`std::atomic_ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref), so supposedly this is fine, if you do everything carefully.

Comment: As for possible UB, are you building with extra warnings enabled? Are you building and running with one or more sanitizer? What do they say?

Comment: What is the actual and underlying problem you need to solve? Why do you think this would solve that problem? And how are you using the union? Will you do type-punning through the union members? And what is `DEDUP_SHIFT`?

Comment: Related: [How can I implement ABA counter with c++11 CAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38984153) discusses the a hacky `union` which is almost certainly UB, but especially without C++20 `atomic_ref` or 16-byte AVX loads being guaranteed atomic now, there was no other way to get a compiler to emit asm that was at all efficient for just loading the 8-byte pointer; the other half of the struct is only useful when updating the pointer to avoid false-positive CASes; reader-only access doesn't need it.  But with `atomic<16byte struct>.member`, stupid compilers want to do a 16-byte atomic load.

Comment: Are the accesses to `seq` and `not_empty` only done during initialization?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The problem is that I multiple threads to be able to the value of `foo.seq`, if they have a higher value, or if `foo` is empty, i.e. `foo.not_empty == 0`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've replace DEDUP_SHIFT #define with its value.

Comment: Your code would not pass code review with me (issues detailed in my answer).  I would just use an `_Atomic uint32_t` directly, or an `_Atomic` struct, without the union shenanigans.  Either way, you read that out by copying its whole value to a non-atomic object, and then picking out the parts of interest from the non-atomic copy.  And the reverse, of course, for updating the object.  That ensures the internal consistency of the parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's all working nicely, but am I causing any undefined behaviour, or other issues, when using unions with an _Atomic member?

C allows you to read back a different member of a union than the one that was last set.  This much is ok in C (but not in C++).  C does not restrict that based on the qualifiers (such as `_Atomic`) of the types involved, so that is not directly a problem.

However,

- `_Atomic` types are not guaranteed to have the same size or representation as their corresponding non-`_Atomic` counterparts, and
- the layout of bitfields within a `struct` is much less constrained than you probably think it is.

Between these, C allows of your example that

- The representation of `value` might not overlap the entirety of the representations of `seq` and `not_empty`.  In an implementation where it does not, your attempts to manipulate those bits atomically via `value` would not have the effect you expect.
- Even if `value` does overlap the entirety of `seq` and `not_empty`, some bits of the latter two might not correspond to value bits of the former. In that case, your attempts to manipulate those bits atomically via `value` might not have the effect you expect.
- Assigning to `seq` and / or `not_empty` might cause `value` to contain a trap representation, even though ordinary `uint32_t` does not have any trap representations.  In an implementation where that can be the case, attempting to manipulate those bits atomically via `value` could cause a trap, possibly crashing the program.  Whether and when this happens could be data dependent.

Additionally, manipulating `_Atomic` object `value` non-atomically via other members of the union seems fraught.  At minimum, such manipulations do not enjoy any of the atomicity guarantees that manipulating `value` directly provides.

So is there undefined behavior here? Hard to say.  There are definitely questions about the behavior that the language spec does not directly address.  Some or all of that might be better characterized as unspecified than as undefined, but the former is not that much better than the latter if you require your program to reproducibly yield the same results on diverse C implementations.

Comment: Side note: I would advise anyone to avoid bitfields to the greatest extent possible.

Comment: On a particular architecture, where `sizeof(union dedup_option_seq) == sizeof(uint32_t) == sizeof(_Atomic uint32_t)`, how could `.seq` and `.not_empty` not be fully covered by `.value`?

Comment: @fadedbee, if you limit the C implementations on which you can rely on your code working to those satisfying sufficient constraints, then you can squeeze out any opportunity for the itemized problems to occur.  That may prove expedient, but it is short-sighted.  Also, it does not protect you from issues related to the trailing, general point that back-door, non-atomic manipulation of an atomic object opens the door to surprising behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your warnings.  Hopefully this is some of my last C work, as I write new code for similar niches in Rust now.