# Why boost::atomic support non-trivial-copyable object?

Tags: c++, boost, stdatomic

boost::atomic requires T to be trivially copyable. But why the following code for `boost::atomic<atom>` works?

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <parallel/algorithm>
#include <boost/algorithm/cxx11/all_of.hpp>
#include <boost/atomic.hpp>
#include <boost/optional/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/count_if.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/remove_if.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/sort.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/unique.hpp>
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>
#include <boost/range/numeric.hpp>


typedef uint32_t vint;  // Integer for vertex IDs

constexpr vint vmax = std::numeric_limits<vint>::max();  // Used as invalid ID

struct atom {
  boost::atomic<float> str;    // Total weighted degree of the community members
  boost::atomic<vint>  child;  // Last vertex that is merged to this vertex
  std::string c;
};

struct vertex {
  boost::atomic<atom> a;
  boost::atomic<vint> sibling;
  vint         united_child;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Is 'atom' trivially copyable? " 
              << std::boolalpha 
              << std::is_trivially_copyable<atom>::value
              << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Reference: https://godbolt.org/z/vEv4jreK9

Comment: Why `boost::atomic` instead of `std::atomic`?  Does it still compile if you try to actually declare a variable of `struct vertex`, whose construction would try to actually construct an `atomic<atom>` non-trivially-copyable object?

Comment: @PeterCordes It's from other's code github.com/araij/rabbit_order/blob/master/rabbit_order.hpp. I'm confused about the atomic<atom> part so I simplified it into the code above

Comment: I'll take your word for it on how that code uses boost::atomic.  But that code looks terrible, using a `union atomix { atomic<T> a; T raw }` with an overloaded `operator->` that returns `&raw` which it claims "has better portability and efficiency" (despite the comment also saying it breaks the strict-aliasing rule).  https://github.com/araij/rabbit_order/blob/f67a79e427e2a06e72f6b528fd5464dfe8a43174/rabbit_order.hpp#L190

Comment: Also losing the visibility guarantees (ant potentially atomicity for larger objects); this is what `a.load(memory_order_relaxed)` and the equivalent `.store` is for!  Perhaps that's how it manages to compile and run with non-trivially-copyable `T` for `atomic<T>` if it doesn't actually use the `boost::atomic<T>` at all for those `T`, only this hacktastic "raw" union member?

Comment: Their `struct atom` doesn't have a `std::string` member, only `atomix<float>` and `atomix<uint32_t>` members for a total of 8 bytes.  It has a copy-constructor and default constructor, but unlike `std::string` it still works if they don't end up getting used and the object-representation just gets copied as if by `memcpy`.

Comment: Presumably they want efficient access to each member separately, as well as the ability to do an atomic RMW on the pair.  With C++11 `std::atomic`, you can abuse the system with a `union { std::atomic<T> a,b; std::atomic<struct both> pair; }` as in [How can I implement ABA counter with c++11 CAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38984153), or with C++20 you can abuse `std::atomic_ref` on either a struct member or the whole struct.  As long as both are lock-free this is safe in asm for real CPUs, although I'm sure it's not officially well-defined behaviour.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Does `struct atom {
  boost::atomic<float> str;    
  boost::atomic<vint>  child;  
};` work with `std::atomic`? I think `struct atom` here is still not trivially copyable.

Comment: Pretty sure `std::atomic` would reject it with compile-time checks.  I'm guessing that `boost::atomic<atom>` doesn't always *use* the constructors (which is why using `boost::atomic<atom>` is UB), sometimes just copying the object-representations like memcpy. But that works because the object-representation for `boost::atomic<float>` is the same as for `float`, which is a primitive value type.  So in practice the it's somewhere between happens-to-work and well-defined, at least on normal implementations like mainstream compilers for real CPUs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not stuck on a C++98 or C++03, then there is no reason to use `boost::atomic`. C++11 added the same functionality standardized as `std::atomic` in `<atomic>`.

And if you are using C++98 or C++03, then there is no way of compile-time checking whether a type is trivially-copyable. The necessary type trait was only added with C++11 and it is impossible to implement it with C++ core language features.

So, in that case the template can't tell you at compile-time that you are giving the it a type that is not allowed. You will simply cause undefined behavior. Checking that the type is trivially-copyable is then your responsibility.

You should really upgrade to C++11 or later. This is only a minor shortcoming of the old C++ language compared to many others.

---

However, I just noticed that you are using some C++11 or later features. So I am confused why you are trying to use `boost::atomic`.

Also, boost should normally compile-time check that the type is trivially-copyable if you compile in C++11 or later mode. However, you are using an old version of boost as well. The compile-time check wasn't yet implemented in 1.68 (presumably because there isn't much use of `boost::atomic` in C++11 mode). It was implemented with [this commit](https://github.com/boostorg/atomic/commit/c4e60c3a65468918f0184b78f258c2ffe0696240) for version 1.73.

Comment: Thanks! I was studying the code from https://github.com/araij/rabbit_order/blob/master/rabbit_order.hpp, which is an efficient graph reordering algorithm. But the atomic<atom> there makes me confused about its actual behavior. The author indeed choose an old boost to use its atomic. Based on your answer, this appears to be a UB.

Comment: The author said "`std::atomic<T>` requires (and checks) that `T` is TriviallyCopyable, and
 hence we resort to use `boost::atomic<T>` instead." So I think there are some unique magic in boost::atomic.

Comment: @VoVAllen No, there is no magic in `boost::atomic`. It is simply UB. The author might still use it, making assumptions about how `boost::atomic` is implemented, how the compiler will translate that implementation into machine instructions and what optimizations the compiler will or will not do. But that's not reliable, especially if compilers, architecture, or in this case the library implementation, change.

Comment: @VoVAllen There is also a comment in there that the implementation breaks aliasing. That is also UB and only happens to work because current common compilers do not optimize based on it when using a union. The way it is mixing atomic with non-atomic access is also UB. The whole implementation is just based on "I know how my compiler compiles this code" at best. It is not backed by any standard specification or library guarantees.